# How to remove title attribute of disabled input

Tags: jquery

I have a text input that contains "disabled" attribute. I want to remove disabled attribute on click of a button but its not working. What is wrong? Even I tried to enable field before removing attribute but no success.

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="ABC()" />

function ABC()

{
    //$("#txtTest").Prop("disabled",false);

    $("#txtTest").removeAttr("title");

    //$("#txtTest").prop("disabled",true);
}
```

Comment: Next time, use your console. You will get a clear error explaining why this does not work.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
$("#txtTest").prop("disabled",false);
```

not

```
$("#txtTest").Prop("disabled",false);
```

**UPDATE**

```
// Remove title from all disabled elements
$('input:disabled').attr('title', '');
```

Or just from one element

```
$('#txtTest').attr('title', '');
```

Comment: +1 - JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: that is commented line, however i changed it and un-commented but no success.

Comment: @TariqMahmood: You mean the title is not removed or the disabled attribute is not removed on click??

Comment: @Jeeeeezus man, I m using firebug but there is no error there

Comment: @Palash Mondal Actually i want to remove title attribute

Comment: Used $('#txtTest').attr('title', ''); but it is not working

Comment: <input type="text" name="txtTest" id="txtTest" title="Test" disabled="disabled"  />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="ABC()" />

Comment: function ABC()
{
 $("#txtTest").attr("title","");
}

Comment: I found that jquery can't remove attribute of a disabled control. So In my html i replaced disabled="disabled" with readonly="true". And now above mentioned code is working fine.